# update cfquery within a cfloop over a query

Tags: coldfusion, cfquery, cfloop

I am going through all the records in the column vals of the Values table and tranforming any absolute urls to relative urls. I get this error

```
[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

On the 3rd to last line of this block of code:

```
<cfquery name="getVals" datasource="#dataBase#">
  Select vals
  FROM Values
</cfquery>

<cfloop 
  query = "getVals">

  <cfset val=#vals#>
    <cfset valEdited= REReplace(
      val, 
      '"(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(example\.com)(\/)?"', 
      "'index.php'", 
      'ALL'
      )>

    <cfquery name="update" datasource="#dataBase#">
      UPDATE   Values
      SET      vals = <cfqueryPARAM value = #valEdited#>
      WHERE    ID = <cfqueryPARAM value = #getVals.currentRow#>
    </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: try using `<cfqueryparam>`, it's not only more secure but it also escapes the varchar string to make sure it'll work.  No single quote needed after `vals =`

Comment: You've also got an extra semi-colon at the end of your `rereplace` line.

Comment: *WHERE ID = #getVals.currentRow#* You should use the unique record `ID`, not the query row number. Also as mentioned, use `cfqueryparam` on *both* variables.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't really query for `select *`.  It is best to only specify the actual column(s) that you need.

Comment: @phantom42 got rid of the semi colons

Comment: @Miguel-F changed the select

Comment: (Edit) Can you post the actual code and **full** error message? That cannot be the actual query, because `values` is a reserved word. So the SQL would not normally run anyway, not without escaping the table name. Plus there is a typo in `update`.

Comment: @Leigh thank you for your unique record ID suggestion!

And I can't post the actual code unfortunately. Fortunately, I got it fixed with all the suggestions!

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would look at is you have a semi colon at the end of the CFSET for ValEdited.
That will blow up first.

Then check your code, to see if it gives you the same error.

A best practice you might want to consider, is only use # when you are outputting values... so

```
<cfset val = getVals.vals>
```

is sufficient.

The next thing I would look at is you where statement.
This assumes all of your values have ID, 1 to the number of records in the table.
If this is not so, you might have to update this to

```
where ID = #getVals.ID#
```

Hope this helps.
By the time I wrote it up, everyone else pretty much said the same thing :P

Comment: Adding onto the point about best practices, `val` is also a CF function. Using it as a variable name works, but it might confuse someone else scanning through the code.

Comment: .. and definitely use `cfqueryparam` too. My guess is their real query is different and the error is because the value matched against `WHERE ID =` is empty. That could certainly cause the `Incorrect syntax near '='. error.`.

Comment: Thank you Gavin, Matt, phantom42 and Leigh! Excellent advice. I took it all. It worked!

Comment: You can just do `<cfset val = vals>` without the 'getvals' because you are already looping inside `getVals`.

Answer (score 0):

personally I wouldn't be updating the values of the column of the query directly. To me  that makes it confusing of exactly what's going on. The approach that I always do is to just add another column to the query using QueryAddColumn().

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_m-r_16.html

This allows you to not only have the changes you need available in the query as a new column, but also leaves the original column alone so you can debug easier. To add the new column just do:

```
<cfquery name="getVals" datasource="#dataBase#">
  Select vals
  FROM Values
  order by id
</cfquery>

<cfset newVals = []>

<cfloop query="getVals">

    <cfset temp = REReplace(
      val, 
      '"(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(example\.com)(\/)?"', 
      "'index.php'", 
      'ALL'
      )>

    <cfset ArrayAppend(newVals, temp)>

</cfloop>

<cfset QueryAddColumn(getVals, "newVals", "Varchar", newVals)>
```

Comment: It seems as if he wants to persist the new values back to the database. How would your solution solve that? Having to massage this data every time he wants to use it seems a bit....wasteful.